# Error en Sentencia: SELECT, JOIN ON CASE

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT nombre , p.DetallePrestaciones, o.Salario
from empleados AS e 
inner join ocupaciones as  o 
on o.PkOcupacion=e.FkOcupacion 
inner join prestaciones as p  
on  p.PkPrestaciones= (CASE MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
WHEN 1 THEN  1
WHEN 7 THEN  2
WHEN 12 THEN  3
ELSE 0
END CASE)
```

Me da el siguiente error:

consulta SQL: Documentación

```
SELECT nombre , p.DetallePrestaciones, o.Salario
from empleados AS e 
inner join ocupaciones as  o 
on o.PkOcupacion=e.FkOcupacion 
inner join prestaciones as p  
on  p.PkPrestaciones= (CASE MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
WHEN 1 THEN  1
WHEN 7 THEN  2
WHEN 12 THEN  3
ELSE 0
END CASE) LIMIT 0, 25
```

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> ## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'CASE) LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 11

Comment: Hola, te damos la bienvenida a Stack overflow en español. Completa el [tour] y lee [ask], luego deberías editar tu pregunta para darle un título más descriptivo y un mejor formato al texto al código y texto. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nombre , p.DetallePrestaciones, o.Salario
from empleados AS e 
inner join ocupaciones as  o 
on o.PkOcupacion=e.FkOcupacion 
inner join prestaciones as p  
on  p.PkPrestaciones= (CASE 
WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())=1 THEN  1
WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())=7 THEN  2
WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())=12 THEN  3
ELSE 0
END)
```

Comment: hola sería genial para ayudar al OP si añades a tu respuesta una explicación en texto para que el compañero se pueda guiar mejor y comprender tu respuesta